# C# v10 not available in Rider 2023.2.2 #file-scoped namespaces

Tags: c#, .net, rider, c#-10.0, jetbrains-rider

After generating a project i .NET7 CLI, I got an error in Jetbrains Rider "Feature 'file-scoped namespaces' is not available. Please use language version 10.0 or greater.
[image]

I tried to change the language version, but in project properties, I haven't an option of 10.0.
I've upgraded Rider to 2023.2.2 build #RD-232.9921.83, Sep 24, 2023 - which is currently the highest release version of Rider IDE - but the problem still persists.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your screenshot makes it look like there are other versions you could scroll to - do they *definitely* not include C# 10? (Is it possible that it's ordering lexicographically, so C# 10 will be right at the bottom?) Have you tried "latest major"?

Comment: @JonSkeet Seems like the list in descending order - but you definitely have a point.

Comment: The screenshot contradicts the question as it shows an option for nullable types in C# 8 and later

Comment: @JonSkeet No, they don't include - here it is, what I have in the scroll:
https://i.ibb.co/0mz1fnk/scr4.jpg
https://i.ibb.co/dQRvvJT/scr5.jpg
Maybe "latest major" could help, I could try.

Comment: Even the top "default" option should be fine if your library is targeting net7.0.

Comment: What's the version of the .NET SDK in use? Run `dotnet --version` in the project directory, or click Right Mouse Button on your Solution in Rider > "Manage .NET SDK...". Perhaps there's a `global.json` selecting an older version of the .NET SDK for you ... but then you shouldn't be able to target .NET 7 actually ... hmmm ... please also show your `.csproj` file. Alternatively, try to set the Language Version manually in your CSPROJ via the MSBuild property `<LangVersion>11.0</LangVersion>`.

Comment: @michael112 My Rider shows C# 11 at the top in *existing* .NET 7 projects. Are you trying to change both the runtime and language at the same time? In any case, in .NET 6 and later the target framework automatically sets the language version to match. In fact, you don't even get a C# version choice when you create a new project targeting .NET 6 or 7.

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
<LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion>
```

in .csproj file has solved the problem.